# How to Manage Deployment/Upgrades for Internal Mobile Application?

Tags: win-universal-app, hockeyapp

I'm creating a UWP application that will be used exclusively on rugged Win10 tablets by a group of initially 10-20.  If things go well it will be expanded to 100 users. These users are employees of our company, but will be remotely located.

Currently, with the test tablets, I am pushing the packages in google drive and manually copying them to the tablets, unzipping and executing the ps file on the tablet.  This is way to complicated for even a beta test group of our users.

I'm looking for short-term/long-term recommendations for deployment.  Someone mentioned SCCM to me and I've read a little, but that seems like quite a major endeavor to host.  I would prefer something like a "private store" concept, but I can't find anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a private store for your company. The best solution is probably to use Windows Store for Business. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/business-store

Microsoft Azure Active Directory (AD) accounts for your employees are needed if you select this solution.

An alternative way is to use HockeyApp http://hockeyapp.net to deploy your application.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check into both of these.  We already require the AD accounts.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any additional details. And if possible please flag as answered if this can help other people. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, HockeyApp should meet your requirement. Via HockeyApp, you can upload and distribute builds for beta or enterprise distribution using our web UI, or our API. HockeyApp also supports build servers like Jenkins or Visual Studio Team Services. Don't forget to upload your dSYM or 
mapping.txt to get readable crash reports.

With HockeySDK for UWP integrated, you can also:

Integrate our open-source SDK to:

- Collect crash reports
- Show update alerts for new beta builds
- Add a feedback view directly into your app

For more information, please visit support.hockeyapp.net.