# How to deploy AppxBundle to multiple windows 10 desktop/tablets remotely?

Tags: windows-10, uwp

I have developed a windows 10 app for a private business, Is there anyway where I can push updates, install the app on multiple windows 10 desktops/tablets from a remote server? What are my options to achieve something like this. I do not want to put it on the windows store for security concerns.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to publish your app to Windows Store, then you can try with [HockeyApp](https://www.hockeyapp.net). Via HockeyApp, you can upload and distribute builds for beta or enterprise distribution using theri web UI, or API.

For more information, see [How to sideload UWP applications](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/how-to-sideload-uwp-applications) and the similar case: [How to Manage Deployment/Upgrades for Internal Mobile Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647510/how-to-manage-deployment-upgrades-for-internal-mobile-application).

Comment: Okay I have also seen an option to deploy using SCCM, can you point in the direction where I should check that out? Also is it possible to install the app for all users on one device?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SCCM. :( And AFALK, we can't install an app for all users on the device. Different user uses different copy of the app, they are isolated from each other.